# how to use ng-model on input component in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code of html file

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController" novalidate="">
<email classname="form-control" name="Email" type="email" modelname="email_id" 
placeholder="Email Address" formref="myForm" ></email>
<button ng-click="Click()">click</button>
```

> i want that when i click the button it gave me the value of the email use the value of the ng-model(email_id) -

```
$scope.Click = function(){
    console.log($scope.email_id);
  };
```

Here is my component code

```
angular.module('textInputExample', []).component("email", {
template:
        '<input type="{{$ctrl.type}}" class="{{$ctrl.classname}}" 
placeHolder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" name="{{$ctrl.name}}" ng- 
model="$ctrl.modelname" required>' +
        '<div ng-messages="$ctrl.formref[$ctrl.name].$error" ng- 
show="$ctrl.formref[$ctrl.name].$touched">' +
        '<p ng-message="required">Providing a {{$ctrl.placeholder}} is 
mandatory.</p>' +
        '<p ng-message="email">{{$ctrl.placeholder}} is invaild</p></div>',

bindings: {
    formref: '<',
    name: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    classname: '@',
    type: '@',
    modelname:'='
}
```

> in above component code i am using that modelname value to assign to ng-model property then i want to use that value in the controller to access the input field value but i doesn't set the ng-model to value which i am assigning it(email_id) and also i can not get access the value of the input field.
>   Please help me what should i do for that.
>   if any information is needed regrading this question to solve the problem please inform me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. here is my solution if anybody trouble with the same problem -

> write this code in your js file

```
component("email", {
bindings: { ngModel: '<' },
require: { ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel' },
template:
        `<input type="{{$ctrl.type}}" class="{{$ctrl.classname}}" placeHolder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" name="{{$ctrl.name}}" ng-model='$ctrl.ngModel'
             ng-change="$ctrl.ngModelChange()" required>
        <div ng-messages="$ctrl.formref[$ctrl.name].$error" ng-show="$ctrl.formref[$ctrl.name].$touched">
        <p ng-message="required">Providing a {{$ctrl.placeholder}} is mandatory.</p>
        <p ng-message="email">{{$ctrl.placeholder}} is invaild</p></div>`,

bindings: {
    formref: '<',
    name: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    classname: '@',
    type: '@',
    modelname:'='
},
controller: function() {
  this.ngModelChange = () => {
    this.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(this.ngModel);
  };
}
```

> Here is the html file code

```
<email classname="form-control" name="Email" type="email" ng-model="email_id" 
placeholder="Email Address" formref="myForm" ></email>
```

**Thank You for my help to everyone**

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="{{$ctrl.type}}" class="{{$ctrl.classname}}" 
placeHolder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" name="{{$ctrl.name}}" ng- 
model="$ctrl.modelname" required>`

try to bind the ng-model and then you can get the values from/to HTML file. Try to change your code with below snippet.

`<input type="{{$ctrl.type}}" class="{{$ctrl.classname}}" 
placeHolder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" name="{{$ctrl.name}}" [(ngModel)]="$ctrl.modelname" required>`

Comment: There is no effect of your code but thank you for your answer

Comment: why? could you please elaborate

Comment: i tried this code but still not working, thanku for your effort